# Large file uploads failing formidable and expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, formidable

I have created a quick upload page but having some issues with large media files.

Pictures and videos under 15mb upload fine, but anything larger and it fails out with a 404 error.

- Dev Lang: JS HTML JQ
- Dev Envir: node@6.10.3, express@4.15.3, body-parser@1.17.2, formidable@1.1.1

So below is my Ajax request on the upload form which can be seen
 [here](http://new.fishpal.com/tools/upload.html)!

```js
   $('.upload-btn').on('click', function () {
      var opt_beats = document.getElementById("opt_beats").checked;
      var opt_rivers = document.getElementById("opt_rivers").checked;

    if (opt_beats == true) {

        $('#upload-input').click();
        $('.progress-bar').text('0%');
        $('.progress-bar').width('0%');

        $('#upload-input').on('change', function () {

            var files = $(this).get(0).files;

            if (files.length > 0) {
                // create a FormData object which will be sent as the data payload in the
                // AJAX request
                var formData = new FormData();

                // loop through all the selected files and add them to the formData object
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    var file = files[i];

                    // add the files to formData object for the data payload
                    formData.append('uploads[]', file, file.name);
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/api/uploader/beats',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('upload successful!\n' + data);
                    },
                    xhr: function () {
                        // create an XMLHttpRequest
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                        // listen to the 'progress' event
                        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (evt) {

                            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                // calculate the percentage of upload completed
                                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                                percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete *
                                    100);

                                // update the Bootstrap progress bar with the new percentage
                                $('.progress-bar').text(percentComplete + '%');
                                $('.progress-bar').width(percentComplete + '%');

                                // once the upload reaches 100%, set the progress bar text to done
                                if (percentComplete === 100) {
                                    $('.progress-bar').html('Done');
                                }

                            }

                        }, false);

                        return xhr;
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    } else if (opt_rivers == true) {

        $('#upload-input').click();
        $('.progress-bar').text('0%');
        $('.progress-bar').width('0%');
        $('#upload-input').on('change', function () {

            var files = $(this).get(0).files;

            if (files.length > 0) {
                // create a FormData object which will be sent as the data payload in the
                // AJAX request
                var formData = new FormData();

                // loop through all the selected files and add them to the formData object
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    var file = files[i];

                    // add the files to formData object for the data payload
                    formData.append('uploads[]', file, file.name);
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/api/uploader/rivers',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('upload successful!\n' + data);
                    },
                    xhr: function () {
                        // create an XMLHttpRequest
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                        // listen to the 'progress' event
                        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (evt) {

                            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                // calculate the percentage of upload completed
                                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                                percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete *
                                    100);

                                // update the Bootstrap progress bar with the new percentage
                                $('.progress-bar').text(percentComplete + '%');
                                $('.progress-bar').width(percentComplete + '%');

                                // once the upload reaches 100%, set the progress bar text to done
                                if (percentComplete === 100) {
                                    $('.progress-bar').html('Done');
                                }

                            }

                        }, false);

                        return xhr;
                    }
                });

            }
        })
    }
});
```

This all hits an API end point which you can see below:

```js
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var path = require('path');
    var formidable = require('formidable');
    var fs = require('fs-extra');

router.post('/beats', function(req, res){

  // create an incoming form object
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

  // specify that we want to allow the user to upload multiple files in a single request
  form.multiples = true;

  // store all uploads in the /uploads directory
  form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '../../public/img/beats');


  // every time a file has been uploaded successfully,
  // rename it to it's orignal name
  form.on('file', function(field, file) {
    fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name));

  });

  // log any errors that occur
  form.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('An error has occured: \n' + err);
  });

  // once all the files have been uploaded, send a response to the client
  form.on('end', function() {
    res.end('Upload End');

  });

  // parse the incoming request containing the form data
  form.parse(req);

});



router.post('/rivers', function(req, res){

    // create an incoming form object
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    // specify that we want to allow the user to upload multiple files in a             single request
    form.multiples = true;

    // store all uploads in the /uploads directory
    form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '../../public/img/rivers');

    // every time a file has been uploaded successfully,
    // rename it to it's orignal name
    form.on('file', function(field, file) {
      fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name));
    });

    // log any errors that occur
    form.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('An error has occured: \n' + err);
    });

// once all the files have been uploaded, send a response to the client
form.on('end', function() {
  res.end('success');
});

// parse the incoming request containing the form data
form.parse(req);

  });

module.exports = router;
```

Screenshot below of Chrome Dev tools logging a success on a small video file but failing on the large.

[image: ConsoleScreen]

I have played with the content types within the ajax request to no avail. Am hoping its a simple over sight and you have enough info to spot it

Below is the expressjs log for the request:

```
[2017-10-06T11:54:56.813Z] Warp speed, Mr Sulu on Port: 3000
[2017-10-06T11:54:56.815Z] CAUTION: You are running this in PRODUCTION mode!!!!
  express:router dispatching OPTIONS /api/uploader/beats +9s
  express:router query  : /api/uploader/beats +4ms
  express:router expressInit  : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router serveStatic  : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +1ms
  express:router dispatching OPTIONS /uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router dispatching OPTIONS /uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router dispatching OPTIONS /uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +4ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router dispatching OPTIONS /uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router dispatching OPTIONS /uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +4ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router dispatching OPTIONS /uploader/beats +4ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router dispatching OPTIONS /uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api/uploader) from url /api/uploader/beats +4ms
  express:router router /api/uploader : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router dispatching OPTIONS /beats +4ms
  express:router dispatching POST /api/uploader/beats +10ms
  express:router query  : /api/uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router expressInit  : /api/uploader/beats +1ms
  express:router serveStatic  : /api/uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /api/uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /api/uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /api/uploader/beats +1ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +0ms
  express:router dispatching POST /uploader/beats +1ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +1ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +1ms
  express:router dispatching POST /uploader/beats +0ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router dispatching POST /uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router dispatching POST /uploader/beats +4ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router dispatching POST /uploader/beats +4ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router dispatching POST /uploader/beats +4ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router dispatching POST /uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api/uploader) from url /api/uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router router /api/uploader : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router dispatching POST /beats +2ms
[2017-10-06T11:57:05.828Z] An error has occured:
Error: Request aborted
  express:router dispatching POST /api/uploader/beats +2m
  express:router query  : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router expressInit  : /api/uploader/beats +4ms
  express:router serveStatic  : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /api/uploader/beats +4ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /api/uploader/beats +4ms
  express:router <anonymous>  : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +4ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router dispatching POST /uploader/beats +4ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +4ms
  express:router dispatching POST /uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +4ms
  express:router dispatching POST /uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +4ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router dispatching POST /uploader/beats +4ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +4ms
  express:router dispatching POST /uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router dispatching POST /uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router router /api : /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router dispatching POST /uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api/uploader) from url /api/uploader/beats +3ms
  express:router router /api/uploader : /api/uploader/beats +2ms
  express:router dispatching POST /beats +3ms
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Express limits the request size by default, to change the limit for a single route you can do this way:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.post('/beats', bodyParser.raw({ limit : '20mb', type : '*/*'}), function(req, res) {
...
});
```

Not sure this is the error as you didnt mention any log on express side, so let me know

Comment: I have added that but issue remains am afraid.

Comment: You're receiving double 404, which is characteristic of a non handled error in express. Can you add an error middleware handler  to your app and see if it logs anything when trying to upload `app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})`

Comment: Will get this up soon, had to do something else which is almost complete so will get this debugging enabled

Comment: Ok have enabled expressjs debugging and you can see the log in my first post.

Also get this error in the browser: 
XHR finished loading: OPTIONS "http://localhost:3000/api/uploader/beats".
12:59:05.935 :3000/api/uploader/beats:1 POST
http://localhost:3000/api/uploader/beats net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
12:59:05.936 XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:3000/api/uploader/beats".

Comment: Fixed it......dunno how to be fair. Was working on some IISnode changes for something else and this started working.

Comment: I'm also stuck in the exactly same issue. What kind of config changes you did in IISnode server?

Answer (score 0):

The Default content length is approximately 30MB. Add this line to the web.config file would fix the problem. This will allow 40MB.

```
<security>
   <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="40000000"/>
   </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Reference Link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/